# How to make a custom bottomNavigationbar widget which is not inside scaffold widget

Tags: flutter

I want to put a floating widget on the bottom of screen just like bottomNavigationBar. But the thing is I'm using the form widget not Scaffold widget. So I'm having trouble on making floating widget always on the bottom of the screen. How can I make it?

Comment: You can create a widget using Stack have width of how long and limit heigt set a container circle to align in center if not can you provide image you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap `FloatingActionButton` and `Form`  with `Stack`,
to Align `FloatingActionButton` at its position wrap it with `Align`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: const MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ),
      Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(height:100,width:100,color:Colors.green),
              
          ],
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```